# Who sets the fees for a transaction?

Tags: transaction-fees

Can I send a transaction with zero fees? And if I could, what would happen? Would miners ignore my request? Who sets the price of fees for transactions?

Answer (score 4):

> Can I send a transaction with zero fees?

You can `create` transaction with zero fee. You can try to broadcast it to your peers. But there is no chance that your peers will accept it and rebroadcast.

> And if I could, what would happen?

The same as for regular transaction with fees. Ignoring zero fee is not a consensus rule, but coded in most nodes.

> Would miners ignore my request?

Today yes

> Who sets the price of fees for transactions?

Market

Answer (score 0):

> Who sets the price of fees for transactions?

You can set fees for your transactions if you use a good wallet, such as electrum.
but the minimium fees accepted by nodes <strike>according to consensus rules</strike> is 1 sat/byte

No matter how congested the network is you can set your transaction to 1 sat/byte. I just did a 1 sat byte transaction few days ago. The network is very congested and it took 3 days to get the first confirmation.

usually a 1 sat/byte fee transaction is confirmed within 6 hours, based in my experience.

Comment: Note: the node relay policy of 1sat/byte minimum is not a consensus rule, it is just the standard policy of nodes, to prevent network spam attacks.